# How to move to code in codebehind from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview .When i click on one row in it i have to go to javascript which is like this.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function GetDetails(rowNo)
            {
                document.getElementById('hidRowNo').value = rowNo
                document.getElementById('btnDet').click();
            }
        </script>
```

I have written following code in codebehind

```
    protected void btnDet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (hidRowNo.Value != "")
        {
            int rowNo = Convert.ToInt32(hidRowNo.Value);
            TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[rowNo].Cells[0].Text;
            TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[rowNo].Cells[1].Text;
            TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[rowNo].Cells[2].Text;
        }
    }



    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GetDetails(" + e.Row.RowIndex + ");");
        }
    }
```

The problem is javascript is working but document.getElementById('btnDet').click(); is not working.While debugging also,control is not moving to btnDet_Click.what change i have to include to move control to btnDel_Click in code behind.

can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
__doPostBack('btnDet','OnClick');
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('btnDet').click();
```

In the server side page load event just add this code...

```
ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDet)
```

Check this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) here

But your code also should work.

Have you tried clicking on the button directly. Does this work?

Comment: This will fire onsubmit event, also. You can use the ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference Method(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) to reduce ability for future mistakes

Comment: when i tried Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDet) showing error as  Public Function Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDet) is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the onclick event is generated for the btnDel button. But on submit form that contains this button was not fired. Thy to replace

```
document.getElementById('btnDet').click();
```

with

```
document.forms[0].fireevent('onsubmit');
```